# How does a software (e.g., MATLAB) compute the value of a hypergeometric series that converges?

Tags: convergence-divergence, hypergeometric-function

I have a hypergeometric function that looks like the following:

$$ G(x) =  {}_p F_p (a, a, a, ..., a; a+1, a+1, a+1, ..., a+1; -i C x), $$
where $p > 1$, $a, C > 0$, and $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

In literature, it is known that the function converges for all $x$ in this case as here the condition $p < q+1$ is satisfied for a generic hypergeometric function $_pF_q$, and the radius of convergence is $\infty$.

So, what does this series converge to? I assume that the software computes this directly?

Comment: https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/3328732

Comment: It has this closed form on [Wolfram functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/03/01/07/0003/)

Comment: @TymaGaidash It is not exactly the same. For me, the arguments $a_i$ are the same. I will update the expression. If I use the closed form you suggested, I have divide by $0$ problem.

Comment: Are you asking about the numerical value of the series sum, or a "closed-form" (not using hypergeometric functions)? The details of the software (such as MATLAB) are almost certainly proprietary unless it is open source such as SageMath or Octave.

Comment: @Somos I’m interested in a numerical sum or a closed form, if it exists. I gave an example of MATLAB because it does find a value and I was curious how to reach a similar solution because it’s a converging series.